# Flag history: some flag names are capitalized, while others aren't

Tags: bug, flag-history

In the [flagging history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current), the `Not an answer` and `Very low quality` flags appear capitalized, while the other flag's names aren't:

[image: Screenshot of bug]

The screenshot was taken on mobile, but the issue also applies to full-site-mode

Comment: not the first time I see such bug. They need to always use lowercase then handle it with CSS and `text-transfrom`. It's the only way to make sure such thing never happen.

Comment: There's a big issue there for localization, @temani - this sort of forced capitalization is not always appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The names are drawn from two different sources - one from FlagTypes, the other from CloseReasons. We recently reworked FlagTypes to reflect our [writing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics#use-sentence-casing); CloseReasons are still on the TODO list.

Eventually, they should be consistent.